# Помощь с преобразованием кнопки

Tags: html, css

Моя кнопка на 2 картинке. Мне нужно чтобы кнопка выглядела как на 1 картинке. Как мне это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.question__btn {
    color: $purple ;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 63px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
  }
  
.question__btn--active {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    color: $white;
    background: $purple;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<button class="question__btn">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас размер в неактивном состоянии отличается от активного. Тем самым при вращении теряется центрирование.

Если использование button не принципиально, то можно использовать следующий вариант: `text-align` и `line-height`

```css
.question__btn {
  color: purple;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 63px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 52px;
  text-align: center;
}

.question__btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  color: white;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="question__btn">+</div>
```

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ, но при данных способах крестик при нажатии сдвигается немного влево. Как сделать чтобы он оставался на месте и никуда не сдвигался, а просто переходил в активное состояние?

Comment: @user512592 обновил ответ

Comment: Огромное спасибо.